# How to show matplotlib plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am sure the configuration of `matplotlib` for python is correct since I have used it to plot some figures.

But today it just stop working for some reason. I tested it with really simple code like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

There's no error but just no figure shown up.

I am using python 2.6, Eclipse in Ubuntu

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In matplotlib you have two main options:

1. Create your plots and draw them at the end:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   plt.plot(x, y)
   plt.plot(z, t)
   plt.show()
   ```
2. Create your plots and draw them as soon as they are created:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from matplotlib import interactive
   interactive(True)

   plt.plot(x, y)
   raw_input('press return to continue')

   plt.plot(z, t)
   raw_input('press return to end')
   ```

Comment: For python 3.x users, use `input` in place of `raw_input`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35168534/2711811.

Answer (score 37):

You must use `plt.show()` at the end in order to see the plot

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone else ends up here using Jupyter Notebooks, you just need

```
%matplotlib inline
```

[Purpose of "%matplotlib inline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027980/purpose-of-matplotlib-inline)

Answer (score 11):

Save the plot as png

```
plt.savefig("temp.png")
```

Answer (score 4):

`plt.plot(X,y)` function just draws the plot on the canvas. In order to view the plot, you have to specify `plt.show()` after `plt.plot(X,y)`. So,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = //your x
y = //your y
plt.plot(X,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `show()` methode when you done all initialisations in your code in order to see the complet version of plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x, y)
................
................
plot.show()
```