# NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Tags: python, raw-input

I'm a seventh grade programmer so I may be missing a lot of things in this program, but for my coding club my instructor asked us to make a guess the number game. I have very limited knowledge on this subject, since I've only attended four classes. Anyway, when I run this program in Python IDLE 3.5 this is what it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\morrris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\guess_that_number.py", line 7, in <module>
name= raw_input()
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

I tried changing the code, but it seems to not like the raw_input().

Comment: Python 3.5 doesn't have raw_input. It has `input()`

Comment: In the future, when you post code, try to post the minimum needed to exhibit the symptom you are asking about.  In this case, `name= raw_input()` is quite sufficient.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know

Answer (score 118):

For Python 3.x, use `input()`. For Python 2.x, use `raw_input()`. Don't forget you can add a prompt string in your `input()` call to create one less print statement. `input("GUESS THAT NUMBER!")`.