# If-Else statement not asking for input in Python

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, input

I am trying to write a basic Twitter scraper in Python and while I have it so that it can scrape for hard coded terms, I'm trying to set it to take the search term from user input.

While my if/else statement accepts input when asked, it then fails to run stating that rawinput is not defined.  The rawinput is within the if statement  I've included my code below

I should mention I'm fairly new to Python.

I've tried removing the rawinput from the if/else and kept it separate but the same issue happens.

```py
userinp = input("Select search type.  1 = tweets.  2 = people")

if userinp == 1:
        entry = rawinput
        query = u'q='
elif userinp == 2:
        entry = rawinput
        query = u'f=users&vertical=default&q='

searchurl = baseurl + query + entry
```

The expected result is that the user selects option 1 or 2 then is asked to enter their search term.

Results are:

```sh
Select search type.  1 = tweets.  2 = people1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Scrape.py", line 22, in <module>
    userentry = rawinput('enter search term')
NameError: name 'rawinput' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: This is a duplicate post.
refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168508/raw-input-is-not-defined please close this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `input()` instead and don't forget the parentheses!

Additionally, `input()` converts your input to a string, so your `if` condition will never be met if it uses integers. Consider replacing with `if userinp == '1':` and `elif userinp == '2':`.

Comment: Ah I thought in Python input was only for integers, not string entries.  Thanks.

Comment: @Angus in python 2 `input()` calls `eval(raw_input())`. in python3 `raw_input` is renamed to `input` and python2's `input` is removed for security reasons

Comment: And of course the `if` statements won't work as planned because `userinp` will never be the number `1` or `2`. We will get the string `"1"` or `"2"` instead.

Comment: This is a duplicate post. refer : stackoverflow.com/questions/35168508/raw-input-is-not-defined please close this pos

Answer (score 1):

It should be `raw_input()` not rawinput. so your code should be like this...

```
userinp = input("Select search type.  1 = tweets.  2 = people")

if userinp == 1:
        entry = raw_input()
        query = u'q='
elif userinp == 2:
        entry = raw_input()
        query = u'f=users&vertical=default&q='

searchurl = baseurl + query + entry
```