# candlestick function not displaying results

Tags: python, matplotlib

When i execute this piece of code the program produces `[None, None, None,...]`

I am expecting candlestick diagram

```
import matplotlib.finance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start =(2014,5,1)    
end = (2014,6,30)

quotes = mpf.quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl('^GDAXI',start, end)
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
mpf.candlestick_ochl(ax,quotes,width=0.6,colorup='b',colordown='r')
plt.grid(True)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(),rotation=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually [show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575062/how-to-show-matplotlib-plots-in-python) your plot on screen. When I copy your code and add

```
plt.show()
```

at the end of it, it runs just fine.