# Need help for py-upset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I wanted to use Python instead of JavaScript for drawing UpSet diagram and find the py-upset on github: https://github.com/ImSoErgodic/py-upset/
I'm using PyCharm as an IDE and downloaded every requirements.

I tried the code below;

```
import pyupset as pyu
from pickle import load
with open('./test_data_dict.pckl', 'rb') as f:
    data_dict = load(f)
    pyu.plot(data_dict)
```

after run the code it says "Process finished with exit code 0" but gives no graph/ diagram. How can I get the diagram? any help?

Comment: did you have `test_data_dict.pckl` file in the folder you're running it from?

Comment: yes i have it. here is a screenshot from ide; https://imgur.com/a/ORhMq

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:
Just realized you are using the command line. MatPlotLib by default renders to a window and doesn't save to a file. See 
[Save plot to image file instead of displaying it using Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib). (I added it below.)

---

I found another package, [UpSetPlot](https://upsetplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that's still being maintained and has more understandable documentation. Here's a short example (note i don't actually know any of the authors or their pizza preference):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import pandas
import upsetplot

pizzas = pandas.DataFrame([
    dict(who="Lex", mushroom=True, pineapple=True),
    dict(who="Gehlenborg", mushroom=True),
    dict(who="Strobelt", pineapple=True),
    dict(who="Vuillemot", ),  # cheese!
    dict(who="Pfister", mushroom=True, pineapple=True), 
    dict(who="Nothman", mushroom=True), 
    dict(who="me", mushroom=True, pineapple=True), 
])

toppings = [c for c in pizzas.columns if c != "who"]
toppings_count_series = pizzas.fillna(False).groupby(toppings).count()["who"]

upsetplot.plot(toppings_count_series, sort_by="cardinality")
current_figure = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
current_figure.savefig("pizza_toppings.png")
```

[image: screenshot of upsetplot plot showing a bar chart and connections between sub categories]

Comment: He specifically asked for help with pyupset not upsetplot?

Answer (score 0):

Type '% matplotlib inline' at the top of your script. 
See for reference: [Purpose of "%matplotlib inline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027980/purpose-of-matplotlib-inline/43028034)

Answer (score 0):

So this may not solve your issue but I had a similar problem (for reasons I haven't researched, but it appears to be a common problem).

The plot is created but just not shown. So to solve this you need to tell *matplotlib.pyplot* to show the chart.

Do this by including the import statement the plt function (from the matplotlib.pyplot library) -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

now at the end of your code and this line -

```
plt.show(pyu)
```

Hope this helps!