# Why can't this Jupyter Code run in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mesa

I am trying to recreate the results of the following [Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/blob/master/examples/forest_fire/Forest%20Fire%20Model.ipynb) by copying the code and running it in PyCharm. When I run the code, I am not able to import numpy or matplotlib because they are showing up in grey, however, the other imports seem to work. I am trying to only recreate up until the 8th line in the Jupyter notebook but when I run that code I do not get any results and my code only finishes with "Process finished with exit code 0".

So I am wondering if copying and pasting from a Jupyter notebook might not be compatible with PyCharm or if someone might be able to provide insight as to why I cannot recreate the image then that would be helpful.

Here is a link to an image of the code I have, it is simply just a copy and paste from the Jupyter Notebook:
[image]

Comment: "I am not able to import numpy or matplotlib because they are showing up in grey" - they're in grey because they aren't used in your code, and you can safely delete these imports. If you weren't able to import them, you'd get errors.

Comment: Do you have any insights as to why in the Jupyter notebook the graphs of line 8 won't appear in PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code in the notebook works because it calls an iPython magic here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline  # this is the iPython magic
```

So, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43028034/4354477), this magic function will *show* the plots right away, while with a regular Python you'll have to call `show`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x, y)  # this line doesn't show anything, it only prepares the plot
plt.grid(True)  # modify the plot
plt.show()  # actually show the plot
```

Try calling `plt.show()` after `results.plot()`.

Comment: The `plt.show()` function worked for me here. As someone new to Python, it's pretty challenging learning all the intricacies! So thank you.