# %Matplotlib - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm running %matplotlib in IPython, but there is a 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Python 3.7; 
MacOs Mojave 10.14.6 (18G84); 
conda matplotlib:  3.1.1  pypi_0   pypi

```
In [13]: import matplotlib                                                      

In [14]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                        

In [15]: %matplotlib                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-a49a4afc47c5> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', '')

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2311                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2312             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2313                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2314             return result
   2315 

<//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-108> in matplotlib(self, line)

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py in matplotlib(self, line)
     97             print("Available matplotlib backends: %s" % backends_list)
     98         else:
---> 99             gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui.lower())
    100             self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
    101 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purpose of "%matplotlib inline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027980/purpose-of-matplotlib-inline)

Comment: Don't use just `%matplotlib`. Use `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: In the (console) IPython notebook, however, you may prefer to not use the "%matplotlib" magic command.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. `%matplotlib` by itself in an ipython shell normally makes figures pop up automatically, and makes them interactive, etc. It has a different purpose than `%matplotlib inline` which embeds figures (and is not what I want). You can get some similar behavior by running `plt.ion()` and picking a suitable backend. Don't know why the `%matplotlib` command doesn't work on some installs though.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib) `%matplotlib` may be supplied with a backend (including, for example, 'inline', 'notebook', 'gtk','qt4' etc.). If a backend option is not supplied it *should* use the default. It looks like this was broken in some version(s) of ipython (see [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/11814) and [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11823)). I've also had some trouble with `%matplotlib` commands with some versions of `matplotlib`.

So, try updating `ipython` and/or `matplotlib` if possible and see if that fixes things.

Alternatively, use `%matplotlib --list` to get available options, then pick one and try (for example):

```
%matplotlib qt
```

If you get into some fancy plotting stuff, sometimes one backend won't work as well as another for a particular case, so you can test run a few and use what works (or is available). Also, if you want to do things directly with figure windows (such as moving figures around on your screen) then those become backend specific. If you're in a `jupyter notebook` try `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib notebook`.

Answer (score 1):

Got here with a similar error message with Jupyter Lab. Was solved for me by placing the backend magic

```
%matplotlib inline
```

in the cell actually doing the plotting.