# What does “‘%’” when calling packages inline in python

Tags: python, inline

I've got a new code which is calling visualization package (matplotlib) in code line and trying to understand the meaning of "%" and "inline" here. What is the definition of each "%" and "inline" ?
"%" is different from "import"?

% matplotlib inline

Comment: You are more likely using ipython not python e.g. Jupyter or Spyder etc. You need to look up ipython magic commands

Comment: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib

Comment: check this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027980/purpose-of-matplotlib-inline

Comment: Thanks guys! I learned more than 5 basic things surfing your links! cheers ;-)