# My plot bar graph isn't showing up. What's wrong with my code

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
%matplotlib notebook
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
CasData.pivot(index='year', columns='CasualtyNumber', values='People').plot(kind='bar')
plt.title('Casualties per year')
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=5)
plt.ylabel('Number of Casualties')
plt.show()
```

My plot bar graph using matplotlib.pyplot isn't showing.
I don't know why but my bar graph isn't showing. I've tried different ways.
If someone could help me out please. I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: [Please don't post an image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Add the code as text.

Comment: Post your code in a formal way. It may help you find the exact response or the answer. Good attempt and try to make your way more formal. Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `%matplotlib notebook`.
It is overriding the previous line (these two lines are setting the backend). `inline` returns static plots, `notebook` is used for interactivity.

You also do not need the `plt.show()` line. This is taken care of by the `inline` backend.

This answer explains more about the backends: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43028034/6709902

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about your code as it seems incomplete but if you're using pivot I assumed you're pulling the data from a ".csv" file.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib notebook

CasData = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

CasData.pivot_table(index='year', columns='CasualtyNumber', values='People').plot(kind='bar')
plt.title('Casualties per year')
plt.xlabel('Year',fontsize='5')
plt.ylabel('Number of Casualties')
plt.show()
```

[image: Image for my plot]

> You need to provide the data in order to plot something and I don't
> see you providing any.