# what does % work next to module, like %matplotlib widget

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I call `%matplotlib widget`, I get

`Error displaying widget: model not found`

I try to solve this problem and I didn't find any decision.

For that reason, I want to understand how % with matplotlip modules work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60856886/3929826