# matplotlib.pyplot is not showing graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

[image: Jupyter notebooks image]

I don't understand why the graph is not showing. All the variables spelled correctly and all the cells seem to work perfectly. But the **matplotlib.pyplot.show()** isn't working. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please paste the code and data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work!

```
%matplotlib inline
```

[Purpose of "%matplotlib inline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027980/purpose-of-matplotlib-inline)