# How can I open plot viewer in vs code jupyter？

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, plot, jupyter-notebook

I am using python to plot in VS code Jupiter on my Mac. The plot is shown in the ***Interactive View***, while I cannot do more thing like zoom or save in the view. I refer to [Python Interactive window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_python-interactive-window)（see Plot Viewer)and it says:

> Within the Python Interactive window, double-click any plot to open it in the viewer, or select the expand button on the upper left corner of the plot.

[Expand Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT1kd.png)

[Plot Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbeUb.jpg)

The expand button is supposed to be shown and open the Plot Viewer, while I don't have the button and there is nothing happen after I double-click the plot.
[No Button Shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dij82.png)

My test code:

```
import seaborn as sns

import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(100)

ax = sns.distplot(x)
```

Could you please help with my issue? I wonder whether I miss any extension. Thank you very much!

Comment: why don't you have the `distplot` deprecation warning? To get the interactive plot windows I run the script on the command line, it would be better if `ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers` had the option to show the interactive plot windows instead of rendering a png

Answer (score 1):

Default the renderer used in Interactive Python windows uses the PNG renderer.

You can change it to use the `TkAgg` renderer (external window)

Add `%matplotlib` to the script

```python
%matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(100)
ax = sns.distplot(x)
```

You can use other [plot renderers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60856886/9938317)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If still does not work please check the version of the `Python` and `Jupyter` extensions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I find that I didn't have Jupyter Note Render option. My Jupyter version is 1.0.0 and my python version is 3.9.7(condo). Could you please tell me what extension I need if you possible. Thanks again.

Comment: @Grylls Leong Very sorry for being late. Have you installed some other jupyter? You need to take the Jupyter which was created by `Microsoft`, and it was bound with `Python` extension. That's means if you have installed `Python` extension, you will not need to install `Jupyter` manually,  and the version of Jupyter was `v2022.2.1030672458` instead of `1.0.0`. If you have installed it, please disable or uninstall it.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT When I want to use the interactive python VSC gives a message you have to install Jupyter in the virtual environment

Comment: @rioV8 Sorry, but in normal you only need to install `ipykernel` in the new environment, it will install the related modules, including `jupyter_client` and `jupyter_core`.