# What does Jupyter notebook call when it presents a matplotlib image?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In Jupyter, if the last statement in a cell returns a `matplotlib.Figure`, the figure is displayed.

One can perform a similar trick with custom classes by providing a `_repr_png_` function in that class. However, matplotlib `Figure`s do not provide this function. This makes me wonder. How does Jupyter "know" what to do with a matplotlib figure?

Comment: As Stef's excellent answer hints at, the plot generation no longer needs to be in the last line in modern, updated Jupyter, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73633497/8508004). In other words, you don't need the `plt.show()` necessarily anymore.

Answer (score 2):

> How does Jupyter "know" what to do with a matplotlib figure?

In the [`inline`](https://github.com/ipython/matplotlib-inline) backend, this is achieved by registering a function to show changed figures ([`flush_figures`](https://github.com/ipython/matplotlib-inline/blob/fbf0ab8f2d81993ff8e319a003f58896c77f2443/matplotlib_inline/backend_inline.py#L108-L152)) with the [`post_execute`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/callbacks.html#post-execute) event in IPython, see [`configure_inline_support`](https://github.com/ipython/matplotlib-inline/blob/fbf0ab8f2d81993ff8e319a003f58896c77f2443/matplotlib_inline/backend_inline.py#L161).