# cant see the cursor location for a plot in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm doing a very simple plot on my Jupyter notebook using matplotlib.pyplot, and I can't seem to get the usual buttons that I could get on PyCharm of "zoom in", "zoom out" etc.
And also I want to display the cursor location and I can't seem to do it.

This is a very simple code example that behaves the same way:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = int(1e3)
x1 = 2
x2 = 6
x = np.linspace(x1, x2, N)

y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show
```

This gives this plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAW3A.png

And I'm missing the following:
[the buttons I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ2Mt.png)
and
[cursor location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQCv5.png)

Comment: There are instructions here for interactive plotting in Jupyter notebooks https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/interactive.html#jupyter-notebooks-jupyterlab

Comment: Your post lacks some details to make it easy to tell you what you need specifically. In general, you need to specify the type of matplotlib backend functionality you want using a magic command at the start of your notebook or plot cell. Modern Jupyter **defaults to inline** as if you included `%matplotlib inline`, which you can find more details about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43028034/8508004). That is what you are seeing; however, you want the interactive features & so you want to put `%matplotlib ipympl`, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example). You may need to ...

Comment: <continued> `ipympl` first. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#installation) and be sure to use conda primarily if that is your chosen, main package manager. `pip` as your backup. You'll see there you can use `%matplotlib widget`, too. This assume you have modern versions. Maybe try `%matplotlib notebook`, if not.  Also note you just need to run a `%matplotlib <choice of backend>` command once per notebook and then it is set. So it is usually put the top or when you do your first plotting cell. `inline` is default and so when you want that you don't need to specify. ...

Comment: <continued> Additionally, the animation [there giving you an idea of the functionality you'll see](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example) leaves it off but you should see the cursor location show below the plot, too.