# Interactive 3-D plots in Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, mplot3d

I have the following code which does produce a 3-D plot in jupyter notebook, but I am unable to get it to be interactive so I can rotate it with the mouse.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generate random dummy data
np.random.seed(42)
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns=['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3'])
VT = np.random.randn(3, 3)
U = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100)


fig2 = plt.figure()
ax = fig2.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for j in range(X.shape[0]):
    x = VT[0, :] @ X.iloc[j, :].T
    y = VT[1, :] @ X.iloc[j, :].T
    z = VT[2, :] @ X.iloc[j, :].T

    if U[j] == 1:
        ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker='x', color='r', s=50)
    else:
        ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker='o', color='b', s=50)

ax.view_init(25, 20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have looked into the issue on several sites (Stack Overflow and GitHub), but it is not quite clear what the remedy may be. using `%matplotlib qt` was suggested, but it throws the exception:

`ImportError: Failed to import any of the following Qt binding modules: PyQt6, PySide6, PyQt5, PySide2`

Trying to install PyQt5 also failed in my Kaggle environment

Answer (score 0):

If you install [ipympl](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/), this variation of your code will work:

```py
%matplotlib ipympl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generate random dummy data
np.random.seed(42)
X_t = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns=['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3'])
VT = np.random.randn(3, 3)
U = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100)


fig2 = plt.figure()
ax = fig2.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for j in range(X_t.shape[0]):
    x = VT[0, :] @ X_t.iloc[j, :].T
    y = VT[1, :] @ X_t.iloc[j, :].T
    z = VT[2, :] @ X_t.iloc[j, :].T

    if U[j] == 1:
        ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker='x', color='r', s=50)
    else:
        ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker='o', color='b', s=50)

ax.view_init(25, 20)
plt.show()
```

The [ipympl Github repo under the matplotlib organization](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl#ipympl) provides additional concise background on usage.

**To demonstrate it without touching your system**:
Click [here](https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/HEAD) to launch directly into a Jupyter session served via MyBinder.
Open a new notebook and paste that code into there and run it. You should be able to left click on the graph and the drag to where you want. Release the left-click when it is where you want. Hit the 'Home' button on the tool widget in the upper left side of the output area to reset the view to the initial point.

That session already had the equivalent of `pip install ipympl` run it. That is what you are seeking for modern interactive plotting with Jupyter, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example).
Note that last link also details that in addition to `%matplotlib ipympl`, you can use `%matplotlib widget`, too. I explain more about the inline default of modern Jupyter and setting the backend option towards the top of your notebook in my comments [here for a pertinent reply to a related question about enabling the interactive backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77635359/cant-see-the-cursor-location-for-a-plot-in-jupyter-notebook#comment136868553_77635359).

Related answer about plots is also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69182917/8508004).

Comment: Thank you kindly for the reply. The code works well in the MyBinder jupyterLab. I need to read the additional info you have provided to enable this on Kaggle as well.

Thank you again
Nader

Comment: [This notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hakami1024/visualizing-loss-function/notebook) makes me think it will work. (Also note that in modern Jupyter, that should preferably be `%pip install ipympl` as it will work in more places. The magic install version was added in 2019 to overcome issues that can arise when using installs in conjunction with an exclamation point, namely not installing to the specific environment where the kernel is running.) Make sure to restart the kernel after the installation step. You may even want to refresh the browser page as well.

Comment: that notebook states:

`#uncomment to get the interactive version (not working in kaggle, download and run locally)
#%matplotlib widget`

Looks like Kaggle may have issues with interactive plots.

Comment: Oops, I missed that comment in the 7th code cell. Sorry. Others, have reported this as an issue it seems, see [here](https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/product-feedback/458237) and [here](https://github.com/hyperspy/hyperspy/issues/2706).