# Ipython freezes after plotting with sympy plot

Tags: python, plot, ipython, sympy, freeze

Whenever i try to plot something and close the plot window after that, I do not return into my Ipython shell. The shell freezes. The only thing I can do is close the shell and start all over again.

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
expr = 2 * x
plot(expr)
```

Gives a nice plot.
But when I close the plot window, the Ipython shell keeps waiting, apparently in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

After searching AGAIN for some time I did find a workaround for this problem with interactive mode:

```
from matplotlib import interactive
interactive(True)
```

Thanks to joaquin who explains it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8575569/9154139