# Matplotlib: y-axis normalised

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataset

```
Date              Type        Label
2020-03-20         A            1
2020-03-20         A            0
2020-03-19         B            1
2020-03-17         A            1
2020-03-15         C            0
2020-03-19         A            0
2020-03-20         D            1
2020-03-20         A            1
```

that I would like to plot with normalised values in a multiple lines plot.
The code below plots the different lines through time

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=[10,6])

(df.loc[df.Label.eq(1),].groupby(["Date","Type"]).agg({"Type":"count"})
 .unstack(1).droplevel(0,axis=1)
 .fillna(method="ffill")
 .plot(ax=ax, kind="line")
)
```

but when I try to apply normalisation

```
column_norm=['Type']
df[column_norm] = df[column_norm].apply(lambda x: (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()))
```

it fails, returning an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

when I calculate min and max.

Can you please tell me how to get a plot with y axis normalised to 1?

Comment: What exactly fails?

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' when I calculate min and max

Comment: `df['Type']` is a string column. What is your expected outcome of a string subtracted from a string?

Comment: @G.Anderson, I believe his `groupby()` above should produce integer counts.

Comment: But anyway, just try to explicitly converting whatever column to numerical for example like `df = df.astype({'column_norm': int})` and see how that goes.

Comment: I have tried and I got this new one. KeyError: 'Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument.'

Comment: It would help to see where in your code you're trying to apply the normalization

Comment: @pavel after the groupby, `'Type'` is no longer in the column labels, which would throw a `KeyError` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the small sample of data and the way that you are using `count` and `fillna` in the code you have shared, I figure that you are wanting to compute the normalized/rescaled [cumulative sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) of the count labels equal to one through time. Here is a step-by-step example of how to do this using a larger sample dataset:

```
import numpy as np   # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd  # v 1.1.3

# Create sample dataset
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1)  # random number generator
dti = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-31', freq='D')
size = 2*dti.size
dfraw = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(Type = rng.choice(list('ABCD'), size=size),
                               Label = rng.choice([0,1], size=size),
                               Date = rng.choice(dti, size=size)))
dfraw.head()
```

[image: dfraw]

You can simplify the reshaping of the dataframe by using the [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) method. Notice how the `df.Label.eq(1)` mask and the aggregation function `count` are replaced here by `aggfunc='sum'` which takes advantage of the fact that `Label` is numeric:

```
dfp = dfraw.pivot_table(values='Label', index='Date', columns='Type', aggfunc='sum')
dfp.head()
```

[image: dfp]

Then the normalized/rescaled cumulative sum can be computed for each variable using the `apply` method:

```
dfcs = dfp.apply(lambda x: x.cumsum()/x.sum(), axis=0)
dfcs.head()
```

[image: dfcs]

Finally, the NaN values can be filled to make the lines in the plot continuous:

```
df = dfcs.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(value=0)
df.head()
```

[image: df]

```
ax = df.plot(figsize=(10,6))

# Format the tick labels using the default tick locations and format legend
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ticklabels = pd.to_datetime(ticks, unit='D').strftime('%d-%b')
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels, rotation=0, ha='center')
ax.legend(title='Type', frameon=False);
```

[image: pandas_line_plot]

Comment: The last part from "ax = df.plot(figsize=(10,6))" and down does not print a plot...What should I do?

Comment: @just_learning I ran this code in Jupyter Notebook which displays plots automatically thanks to [IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html#rich-outputs) (v7.21.0 with default settings). If you are not using IPython try adding `ax.figure.show()` at the end of the code or `plt.show()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575062/how-to-show-matplotlib-plots-in-python).

Comment: Neither "ax.figure.show()" nor "plt.show()" works! I use Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: @just_learning I am using Windows 10 and I can print the plot in regular Python just the same as with IPython so I am not able to be of further help on this issue as I cannot reproduce the problem. Maybe one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show) (or among the linked questions) may help.